# Avoid scaling binary columns in sci-kit learn StandsardScaler

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multi-dimensional-scaling

I'm building a linear regression model in sci-kit learn, and am scaling the inputs as a preprocessing step in a sci-kit learn Pipeline. Is there any way I can avoid scaling binary columns? What's happening is that these columns are being scaled with every other column, causing the values to be centered around 0, rather than being 0 or 1, so I'm getting values like [-0.6, 0.3], which cause input values of 0 to influence predictions in my linear model.

Basic code to illustrate:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
>>> X = np.hstack( (np.random.random((1000, 2)),
                np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 2))) )
>>> X
array([[ 0.30314072,  0.22981496,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.08373292,  0.66170678,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.76279599,  0.36658793,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       ...,
       [ 0.81517519,  0.40227095,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.21244587,  0.34141014,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.2328417 ,  0.14119217,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
>>> scaler = StandardScaler()
>>> scaler.fit_transform(X)
array([[-0.67768374, -0.95108883,  1.00803226,  1.03667198],
       [-1.43378124,  0.53576375,  1.00803226, -0.96462528],
       [ 0.90632643, -0.48022732,  1.00803226, -0.96462528],
       ...,
       [ 1.08682952, -0.35738315, -0.99203175, -0.96462528],
       [-0.99022572, -0.56690563, -0.99203175, -0.96462528],
       [-0.91994001, -1.25618613, -0.99203175, -0.96462528]])
```

I'd love for the output of the last line to be:

```
>>> scaler.fit_transform(X, dont_scale_binary_or_something=True)
array([[-0.67768374, -0.95108883,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [-1.43378124,  0.53576375,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.90632643, -0.48022732,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       ...,
       [ 1.08682952, -0.35738315,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [-0.99022572, -0.56690563,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [-0.91994001, -1.25618613,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Any way I can accomplish this? I suppose I could just select the columns that aren't binary, only transform those, then replace the transformed values back into the array, but I'd like it to play nicely with the sci-kit learn Pipeline workflow, so I can just do something like:

```
clf = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('ridge', Ridge())])
clf.set_params(scaler__dont_scale_binary_features=True, ridge__alpha=0.04).fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 7):

You should create a custom scaler which ignores the last two columns while scaling.

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
import numpy as np

class CustomScaler(TransformerMixin): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler()

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.scaler.fit(X[:, :-2], y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X_head = self.scaler.transform(X[:, :-2])
        return np.concatenate(X_head, X[:, -2:], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm posting code that I adapted from @miindlek's response just in case it is helpful to others. I encountered an error when I didn't include BaseEstimator. Thank you again @miindlek. Below, bin_vars_index is an array of column indexes for the binary variable and cont_vars_index is the same for the continuous variables that you want to scale.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np

class CustomScaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin): 
    # note: returns the feature matrix with the binary columns ordered first  
    def __init__(self,bin_vars_index,cont_vars_index,copy=True,with_mean=True,with_std=True):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean,with_std)
        self.bin_vars_index = bin_vars_index
        self.cont_vars_index = cont_vars_index

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.scaler.fit(X[:,self.cont_vars_index], y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None, copy=None):
        X_tail = self.scaler.transform(X[:,self.cont_vars_index],y,copy)
        return np.concatenate((X[:,self.bin_vars_index],X_tail), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 5):

I have adapted @J_C code a bit to work with pandas data frame. You can pass column names that you want to scale and you get result with initial column order.

```
enter code here
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import pandas as pd

class CustomScaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin): 
    def __init__(self,columns,copy=True,with_mean=True,with_std=True):
        self.scaler = StandardScaler(copy,with_mean,with_std)
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.scaler.fit(X[self.columns], y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None, copy=None):
        init_col_order = X.columns
        X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(X[self.columns]), columns=self.columns)
        X_not_scaled = X.ix[:,~X.columns.isin(self.columns)]
        return pd.concat([X_not_scaled, X_scaled], axis=1)[init_col_order]
```

Usage:

```
scale = CustomScaler(columns=['duration', 'num_operations'])
scaled = scale.fit_transform(churn_d)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your pipeline should change into:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline,FeatureUnion


pipeline=Pipeline(steps= [
    ('feature_processing', FeatureUnion(transformer_list = [
            ('categorical', FunctionTransformer(lambda data: data[:, cat_indices])),

            #numeric
            ('numeric', Pipeline(steps = [
                ('select', FunctionTransformer(lambda data: data[:, num_indices])),
                ('scale', StandardScaler())
                        ]))
        ])),
    ('clf', Ridge())
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the concatenation in @Vitaliy Grabovets dataframe version doesn't work properly unless you specify the index for X_scaled. So the relevant line now reads:

```
X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(self.scaler.transform(X[self.columns]), columns=self.columns, index=X.index)
```

Answer (score 3):

This probably makes it easier for you

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    X = np.hstack((np.random.random((1000, 2)),np.random.randint(2, size=        (1000, 2))))

    df=pd.DataFrame(X,columns=["num_1","num_2","binary_1","binary_2"])

    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

    num_pipeline = Pipeline([            
        ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ])

    num_attribs=["num_1","num_2"]
    binary_attribs=["binary_1","binary_2"]


    full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
        ("num_cols", num_pipeline, num_attribs),
        ("binary_cols",OneHotEncoder(drop="first"),binary_attribs),
    ])

    full_pipeline.fit_transform(df)
```